# Apend the values from one dataframe to another based on index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes df1 and df2. df2 is the subset of df1

```
df1 = df1=[[0,1,0,0],
      [1,2,0,0],
      [2,0,0,0],
      [2,4,0,0]]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1,columns=['A','B','C','D'])
>>> df1
   A  B  C  D
0  0  1  0  0
1  1  2  0  0
2  2  0  0  0
3  2  4  0  0

>>> df2
   C  D
2  1  3
3  2  4
```

I want to append the value of C and D from df2 to df1 based on index.

My expected output:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  0  1  0  0
1  1  2  0  0
2  2  0  1  3
3  2  4  2  4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

*notice*: this is `inplace`, so it overwrites your `df1` without having it to assign back

Quoted from the docs:

> Modify in place using non-NA values from another DataFrame.
>
> Aligns on indices. There is no return value.

```
df1.update(df2)
```

```
   A  B    C    D
0  0  1 0.00 0.00
1  1  2 0.00 0.00
2  2  0 1.00 3.00
3  2  4 2.00 4.00
```

---

To convert back to `int`, use `DataFrame.astype`:

```
df1 = df1.astype(int)

   A  B  C  D
0  0  1  0  0
1  1  2  0  0
2  2  0  1  3
3  2  4  2  4
```

---

Another solution, but less elegant, is to use `addition` and then `fillna`:

```
(df1 + df2).fillna(df1).astype(int)
```

Or

```
df1.add(df2).fillna(df1).astype(int)
```

```
   A  B  C  D
0  0  1  0  0
1  1  2  0  0
2  2  0  1  3
3  2  4  2  4
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using `reindex_like` and `fillna`

```
df_final = df2.reindex_like(df1).fillna(df1).astype(int)

Out[89]:
   A  B  C  D
0  0  1  0  0
1  1  2  0  0
2  2  0  1  3
3  2  4  2  4
```